# Saving the DateTime format applied in the .csv file in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, export-to-csv

I have imported a csv file in pandas that contains fields that look like `'datetime'` but initially parsed as `'object'`. I make the required conversion from `'datetime'` to `'object'` using `'df.X = pd.to_datetime(df.X)'`.

Now, when I try to save these changes by writing this out to a new .csv file and importing that, the format is still `'object'`. Is there anyway to fix it's datatype so that **on importing** it I don't have to perform the conversion everytime? My dataset is quite big and conversion takes some time, which I want to save.

Comment: No, a `.csv` is just a text file so you can't store that kind of information. You can use other file formats like [`.pkl`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html), or you need to use the `parse_dates` argument of `pd.read_csv`

Answer (score 1):

Date parsing can be expensive, so pandas doesn't parse dates by default. You need to specify parse_dates argument when call read_csv

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', parse_dates=['date_column'])
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.